# Intersection of two subgroups is a normal subgroup of another Intersection of two subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $\mathrm G$ be a group. $\mathrm H$ and $\mathrm K$ subgroups of $\mathrm G$ such as $\mathrm H$$\lhd$$\mathrm K$. Prove that for any subgroup $\mathrm L$ of $\mathrm G$, we have

$\mathrm H$$\cap$$\mathrm L$$\lhd$$\mathrm K$$\cap$$\mathrm L$

I've proven that $\mathrm H$$\cap$$\mathrm L$ and $\mathrm K$$\cap$$\mathrm L$ are both subgroups of $\mathrm G$ what I can't prove in mathematical writing is that $\mathrm H$$\cap$$\mathrm L$ is a ?$normal  subgroup$? of  $\mathrm K$$\cap$$\mathrm L$

Is this starting a way of getting there?

$\forall$n$\in$($\mathrm H$$\cap$$\mathrm L$) $\forall$m$\in$($\mathrm K$$\cap$$\mathrm L$) : $mnm^{-1}$ $\in$ ($\mathrm H$$\cap$$\mathrm L$) and 
 $\forall$n$\in$ ($\mathrm H$$\cap$$\mathrm L$) $\forall$m$\in$($\mathrm K$$\cap$$\mathrm L$) : $mn$$m^{-1}$ $\in$ ($\mathrm K$$\cap$$\mathrm L$)

Comment: You need to show that if $m\in K\cap L$ and $n\in H\cap L$ then $mnm^{-1}\in H\cap L$. Did you prove it or not?

Comment: I did indeed prove that, then what are you saying? Is solved just by that? Cause it's seems a little trivial then

Comment: Well, yes. What is your definition of a normal subgroup? There are many equivalent definitions, one of them is that $N\trianglelefteq G$ if for all $g\in G, x\in N$ we have $gxg^{-1}\in N$. (assuming that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ of course)

Comment: FYI: You don't have to place a `$` on both sides of *every symbol*; instead, it is enough to put them at both sides of a string of symbols, like `$\alpha\beta\gamma$` for $\alpha\beta\gamma$.

Comment: I got that. What's keep bugging my ear it's that $\mathrm H$ is already a normal subgroup of $\mathrm K$ and $\mathrm K$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm G$. Wich I think makes $\mathrm H$ $\subseteq$ $\mathrm K$ $\subset$ $\mathrm G$

Answer (score 1):

Given $x\in K\cap L$ then $xLx^{-1} = L$ because $x\in L$ while $xHx^{-1}=H$  because $x\in K$ and $K$ is contained in the normalizer of $H$. Therefore, because $g\mapsto xgx^{-1}$ defines a permutation on $G$, namely the $G$ inner automorphism induced by $x$, we must have

$$x(H\cap L)x^{-1}=xHx^{-1}\cap xLx^{-1}=H\cap L$$